# Transform an ItemGroup into a Delimited String

Tags: msbuild, transform, itemgroup

My question is almost identical to [Create an ItemGroup of strings in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498374/create-an-itemgroup-of-strings-in-msbuild) however the solution offered there still seems to carry over the existing delimiter. Here's a simplified snippet of what I'm attempting to do:

```
<Target Name="Testing">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="$(RootDirectory)\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="@(Files->'%(Filename)%(Extension) ')"/>
</Target>
```

My desired output is something that looks like this:

```
file1.cs file2.cs file3.cs
```

However the snippet above produces the following output

```
file1.cs ;file2.cs ;file3.cs
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try to use [MSBuild transforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-transforms) like this:

```
    <Message Text="@(Files->'%(Filename)%(Extension)', ' ')"/>
```

Comment: Excellent, +1 for linking to the MSDN documentation as well, don't know why I didn't find that in my earlier searches.